# Fullcalendar show free slots every 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar right now with the 'agendaweek' view.

I want to display the free slots to clickable and showing the busy one's with a red backgroup. For the busy ones's that no problem.

But is there an option for the fullcalender to show like from 8ap till 6pm free slots each 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: That was a link to the old docs, whoops. Corrected now.

Yes there is, it is "slotDuration".

Like this

```
slotDuration:"00:15:00"
```

Source is [FullCalendar - slotDuration](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/)

Comment: Thanks! But i want to show like a background image with all free slots available and make them clickable.